# Is there a way to show all answers and their comments while editing an answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editor

Is there a way to show the question's comments, all of its answers, as well as the answers' comments while editing an answer?

If not - is there anyone else who thinks it would be convenient to have that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

But you have to earn [full editing rights](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) first. That gives you access to the *inline editor*, which allows you to edit posts without leaving the question page. Heck, you can edit the question and multiple answers simultaneously if that suits you.

Until you earn this privilege, you'll want to keep the question open in a separate tab, for reference while editing.

Comment: Interesting. I get the gamification concept in SO, but why make this feature reputation-dependent? I would guess SO would strive to make answering as convenient as possible, even for users with low reputation...

Comment: I don't think it's really about gamification here, @obe. The full edit page has editing help in the sidebar and UI elements specific to suggested edits; the inline editor, being inline, doesn't.

Comment: I see... ok, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes !

- You can open the editor in a new tab (right click on the edit link > open in new tab), and then you can switch back and forth between them.
- Or you could try [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6216/inline-editor-regardless-of-reputation) (Greasemonkey or similar required), which gives you the inline editor regardless of reputation.